# google oauth user profile

Tags: php, oauth

I have used the google oauth to fetch the emails using three legged approach.
I want to access the user profile of the person who has logged into the gmail during oauth authentication?
Any google data api does this i mean the user profile information of the user.Also how to / where to write that pece of code?
Mark

Answer (score 2):

Wrote an article just for you
http://kurapov.name/eng/tech/google_oauth
:)

Answer (score 1):

You could fetch the user's Google profile with the userinfo API, or the Google+ API.

Here's a sample application demonstrating how you can use the userinfo API:
http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/browse/trunk/examples/userinfo/index.php

Here's one using the Google+ API:
http://code.google.com/p/google-plus-php-starter/